# Vector vs. multi-step for LSTM time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Assume we want to predict a sequence of values of a time series with an LSTM.

---

**Question:** What are the pros and cons of using a multi-step approach compared to merely using an output vector containing the sequence of values that we want to predict?